# What is the best javascript based profile pic editor that works with a django backend?

Tags: javascript, widget, django

I am creating a profile picture upload service for a website, where we would like to be able to scale,rotate, and crop the images before they are saved on the server, with a standard width and height. Are there any front end javascript based widgets to perform this task that play nice with django on the back end?